# Can you explain why this solution to rust's borrow checker error?

Tags: rust

This might not be the right place to ask this, but I'm working on interview questions in Rust. The problem is to define an in-memory FileSystem and I'm using a recursive `FileSystem` type plus `Node` enum.

```rust
enum Node {
  File(String),
  Directory(FileSystem)
}
struct FileSystem {
  storage: HashMap<String,Box<Node>>
}
```

Here was my first attempt at implementing mkdir,

```rust
impl FileSystem {
...
 
    fn mkdir(&mut self, path: String) {
      let directories = path.split("/").map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
      let mut curr = self;
      for dir in &directories {
        if !curr.storage.contains_key(dir) {
          let filesystem = FileSystem::new();
          let new_node = Box::new(Node::Directory(filesystem));
          curr.storage.insert(dir.to_string(), new_node);
        }
        if let Some(&mut f) = curr.storage.get_mut(dir) {
          match *f {
            Node::Directory(d) => *curr = d,
            _ => unreachable!()
          }
        }
      }
    }
...
}
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Line 62, Char 31: cannot move out of a mutable reference (solution.rs)
   |
62 |         if let Some(&mut f) = curr.storage.get_mut(dir) {
   |                          -    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                          |
   |                          data moved here
   |                          move occurs because `f` has type `Box<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
Line 74, Char 13: borrow of moved value: `self` (solution.rs)
```

and chatgpt gave me the following solution that compiles, but I'm having trouble grokking the underlying reason that tossing the `Box` inside a closure fixes the borrow checker error.

```rust
impl FileSystem {
...
fn mkdir(&mut self, path: String) {
      let directories = path.split("/").map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
      let mut curr = &mut self.storage;
      for dir in directories {
        let next = curr.entry(dir).or_insert_with(|| Box::new(Node::Directory(FileSystem::new())));
        match next.as_mut() {
          Node::Directory(d) => curr = &mut d.storage,
          _ => unreachable!()
        }
      }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&mut` in pattern position will *dereference* the value.

`HashMap::get_mut` already returns an `Option<&mut T>` `Some(f)` would have created an `f` of type `&mut T` which is what you wanted. There are exceptions but generally the pattern does the reverse of the value literal so:

```
  value: Some(&mut T)
pattern: Some(&mut f)
```

thus `f: T`, and rust has to dereference and try to move the value for that to work, which it doesn't because `Node` is not `Copy`.